# Need to convert JSON to an Array in same order

Tags: .net, arrays, json

I need to use a huge JSON with 8000 elements (classes/subclasses) in it. I need to get it as a straight array (1-8000) in same sequence. Can i do with out creating classes?

Dictionary object doesn't give me orderly items.

```
{
"Root":{
  "A":{
     "Q1":"1",
     "Q2":"2",
     "Q3":"3"
  },
  "B":{
     "Q1":"4",
     "Q2":"5",
     "Q3":"6"
  },
  "X":{
     "Y1":"11",
     "Y2":"22"
  }
},
"SUB":{
  "A":{
     "Q1":"10",
     "Q2":"20",
     "Q3":"30"
  },
  "X":{
     "Y1":"110",
     "Y2":"220"
  }
 }
}
```

Convert something like below array

```
  A-Q1,1
  A-Q2,2
  A-Q3,3
  B-Q1,4
  B-Q2,5
  B-Q3,6
  X-Y1,11
  X-Y2,22
  SUB-A-Q1,10
  SUB-A-Q2,20
  SUB-A-Q3,30
  SUB-X-Y1,110
  SUB-X-Y2,220
```

Comment: How about List object? I guess should generate the same order as it was in JSON.

Comment: Is the "huge JSON" an actual hash object? If so it would be wrong of you to expect its fields to be in any particular order. If not, then post some code so we can see what the issue is.

Comment: added requirement w/ an example

Comment: Ok, so it is like I said. It is wrong of you to expect keys to be in any particular order.

Comment: What do you mean by "without creating classes"?

Comment: For parsing this JSON, i may have to create 16 classes/700 properties for parsing it. Thats what i need to avoid. Rather looking for list(s) of list/array so that i just need to read by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, in JSON:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

Your options are:

1. Change the source so it provides an array of objects instead of a set of key/value pairs
2. Write a custom parser that doesn't treat it as JSON, but parses it into a data structure that you prefer